# How to establish an RDP connection to an Azure virtual machine availability set?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp, azure-availability-set

I created a new virtual machine scale set that's deployed over two availability zones, and I configured a load balancer and virtual network for the scale set.  Now I want to connect to this new VM via RDP (in the same way I can connect to a standalone VM), but no such option seems to exist for the scale set.

---

Standalone VM:
[image]

---

Scale set VM:
[image]

---

**How can I enable an RDP option for this new VM?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a scale set in the portal, a load balancer is created. Network Address Translation (NAT) rules are used to distribute traffic to the scale set instances for remote connectivity such as RDP or SSH.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-portal#connect-to-a-vm-in-the-scale-set